# rpxnow - How to promote users to sign in

Tags: authentication, openid, rpxnow

Since adding [rpxnow](https://rpxnow.com/) to our website, less users are signing in.
Are these readers worried about giving their (eg hotmail) password to a third party site?

Has anyone found a good way to promote use of rpxnow (or other openid managers) as a secure method of authentication to non tech savvy readers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are a number of ways to promote third party login.  Universal Music Group and the LA Times have good implementations that pre-message to site visitors how easy it is to login using existing accounts at Yahoo, Google, Facebook, Twitter, AOL, etc.

John Beutler at Janrain can give you some advice: johnb at janrain.com

Comment: I think the answer is to build a trustworthy website with returning visitors.